# Is there a name for the bias addition after weight multiplication in Neural Network literature?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

My question is, what is this step called (if at all):

$$
W_2a_2 + b_2
$$

This is what each neuron does, and then the activation layer decides how much participation this neuron will take in the next layer:
$$ \sigma(W_2a_2 + b_2) $$

But is there a name to the previous step? I see this as basic transformation of the type:
$$ y = mx + c $$
Is simply `transformation` an appropriate name for this step?

Comment: some people call it the weighted input to the neurons of the next layer

Comment: I see. But that does not address the bias term, right?

Comment: some people include the bias term and some dont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by biological neurons, this has been recently called **post-synaptic potential**. The name sounds complicated, but actually corresponds nicely to the meaning of this term: the potential of a neuron after absorbing its inputs, before the value gets passed to the non-linear activation function deciding whether this neuron will fire or not.

See *[Tartaglione et al., 2019: Post-synaptic potential regularization has potential](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.08544)*.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case where the activation function is the logistic sigmoid, then the inputs are sometimes called logits, since the [logit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) is the inverse of the logistic function. More generally, I have seen the term "pre-activation" used. Either way, I don't think there's a universally accepted name for this step.

Comment: hm, this (the usage of the term "logits") is only true though if a) you are talking about the output layer b) you have a classification task and c) if you use the logistic sigmoid or softmax as the activation function of the output layer. Pre-activation is better. In older neural network literature it's also called "net inputs"

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics

$$
y = mx + b
$$

is called a [linear equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation). In neural networks, people would usually call it a linear transformation of the data, as opposed to non-linear transformations in activation functions.